# Split data in a line using unix

Tags: unix, csv, awk

How do you use the unix to create a csv file where each field is a column?

My data is:

```
>A::LOLLLL rank=1 x=2 y=9 length=10 


Column 1    Column 2     Column 3 
>A          LOLLLL       10
```

I tried using `awk '{print $1}'input_file` to try to separate between the fields but the terminal reads out `command not found`. I wanted to use this to then have each field I am interested in turned into a separate `txt.file` where I can change the extension to `.csv` and combine manually. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you want to pipe your file from cat to awk

Comment: @Kevin: You *never* want to pipe from cat to anything. Just redirect the input of the "anything" in question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
echo ">A::LOLLLL rank=1 x=2 y=9 length=10" | awk -F"[: =]" '{print $1,$3,$NF}' OFS="\t"
>A      LOLLLL  10
```

---

To get to separate files:

```
awk -F"[: =]" '{print $1 >"c1.csv";print $3 >"c2.csv";print $NF >"c3.csv"}' file
```

Comment: @Jotne there is one small typo its `print $NF >` not `print $NF1 >` right ?